# Design ideas regading a WinSock2 wrapper

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock, winsock2

Let's have classes `Ip::Address` and `Ip::Endpoint`.

**First design idea.**

```
Ip::Address
Ip::Address::Address(const std::string& stringRepresentation)
```

This class would be internally represented as either an `in_addr` or an `in6_addr`.

```
Ip::Endpoint
Ip::Endpoint::Endpoint(const Ip::Address& address, const std::uint16_t port)
```

This class would contain an `Ip::Address`, and also be internally represented as either a `sockaddr_in` or a `sockaddr_in6`.

This is the design I've come up with, but I'm not really happy with it. The reason is the following. Let's take the IPv4 case. An `Ip::Endpoint` is internally represented as a `sockaddr_in` which contains an `in_addr`. Since an `Ip::Endpoint` also contains an `Ip::Address` which is internally represented as an `in_addr`, the `in_addr` structure appears in an `Ip::Endpoint` twice.

**Second design idea.**

```
Ip::Address
Ip::Address::Address(const std::string& stringRepresentation)
```

This class would be internally represented as either a `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`.

```
Ip::Endpoint
Ip::Endpoint::Endpoint(const Ip::Address& address, const std::uint16_t port)
```

This class would contain an `Ip::Address` and also use its internal representation to internally represent itself - `Ip::Endpoint` will rely on `Ip::Address::Internal` (`sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`).

This approach would eliminate having two `in_addr`/`in_addr6` structures for an `Ip::Endpoint`. But it would also make the `Ip::Address`' internal representation 'too big'. An `Ip::Address` only needs `in_addr`, but not `sockaddr_in`.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Just a thought, look at `boost::asio`, it has a nice design (IMO, others will disagree...)

Comment: @Nim, asio's ip::endpoint is internally represented as a sockaddr_in/sockaddr_in6. And when you ask an ip::address from it, it will be reconstructed from sockaddr_in::in_addr. I don't really like the idea of taking an Ip::Address and port in the constructor and then just throwing the Ip::Address away - just to reconstruct it when the user of the library does Ip::Endpoint::address().